# How to get xmlns attributes using lxml objectify?

Tags: python, attributes, lxml, xml-namespaces

I have several xml documents i am dealing with. They have differing root elements. Here are some of them.

```
<rss xmlns:npr="http://www.npr.org/rss/" xmlns:nprml="http://api.npr.org/nprml" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0">
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="/~d/styles/rss2enclosuresfull.xsl"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://feeds.thisamericanlife.org/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?><rss xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" version="2.0" xml:base="http://www.thisamericanlife.org">
```

I am using lxml in the following way on the first example from above.

```
>>> from lxml import objectify
>>> root = objectify.parse('file_for_first_example').getroot() # contains valid xml with first above element
>>> print root.tag
'rss'
>>> root.attrib.keys()
['version']
>>> for k in root.attrib.iterkeys():
>>>    print k
version
>>> print root.get("xmlns:npr")
None
```

I just want to be able to sense what these 'attribute' values are so i can, i believe, infer what the format of the various feeds are.

Thanks for the help in advance. Love and peace.

Answer (score 7):

The namespace declarations are namespace nodes. Looks like you want the `.nsmap` property http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

```
xhtml.nsmap
{None: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'}
```

Comment: I'm trying to discover why the namespace nodes wouldn't be included in the `attrib` property but I'm not too familiar with lxml.

Comment: Looks like it's from the way the ElementTree implementation maps all namespaced elements to their universal names. http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm#element-tree-representation

Comment: I wonder why I cannot find the `nsmap` class variable in the API docs http://lxml.de/api/xml.etree.ElementTree.Element-class.html

Comment: I see now, it is in private class `_Element` of module `etree`: http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html